# Why does the image not shrink (responsively) when the browser shrinks?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have an example (with the help from @bjb568) here. Please click it to see how it works in Chrome/IE/FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/P92Fs/11/

Here is all code.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<div class="media">
    <img src="http://www.trumba.com/i/DgCAOmnZFp7ia4FDZJne5SHC.gif" />
    <div class="caption">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.
    </div>
</div>
</div>

.media {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.media .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

In Chrome (Windows), the image shrinks accordingly when the browser's viewport is narrower than the image width. This is what I want.

However, it does not shrink accordingly in IE (v10, Windows) and Firefox (v26, Windows).

Does anyone know why and the fix?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the difference may be in the way the browsers are determining what you meant by 100%. Chrome seems to think it is a reference to the parent element, FF seems to think it means 100% of the image size.

Comment: Oddly enough adding a min-width didn't seem to fix it as expected. Seems as though all relative sizing doesn't mix with FF. Need a literal somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `img`, change `max-width` to `width` in your CSS.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P92Fs/18/).

Max-width just sets the maximum width, not the actual width.

Comment: If you are using the img elements you might want to use width:100%; max-width:100%; and display:block; for good measure. Omitting the display:block can get you into trouble later on.

Comment: @Smith I updated the fiddle with your recommendations — Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in the head section of your html document?

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

It's a little hard to troubleshoot without seeing the whole html document.

Comment: Yes, I have that line, but it appears it has no effect. All the code is very simple and you can see it in the fiddle example.

Comment: Can you post a link to the HTML page?

Comment: Please see the fiddle link in the post.